# Custom built JSON schema not validating properly

Tags: go, jsonschema

I have a custom built JSON schema that only has a few more top-levels. The problem here is that it doesn't validate everything to 100%. For example, it only detects 2 out of 4 fields, and the required fields do not work at all, neither does additionalproperties, etc. I'm using [this library](http://github.com/xeipuuv/gojsonschema) for my json schema.

```
{
    "users": {
        "PUT": {
          "definitions": {},
          "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
          "$id": "http://example.com/root.json",
          "type": "object",
          "title": "The Root Schema",
          "required": [
            "DisplayName",
            "Username",
            "Email",
            "Password"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "DisplayName": {
              "$id": "#/properties/DisplayName",
              "type": "string",
              "title": "The Displayname Schema",
              "default": "",
              "examples": [
                ""
              ],
              "minLength": 3,
              "maxLength": 24,
              "pattern": "^(.*)$"
            },
            "Username": {
              "$id": "#/properties/Username",
              "type": "string",
              "title": "The Username Schema",
              "default": "",
              "examples": [
                ""
              ],
              "minLength": 3,
              "maxLength": 15,
              "pattern": "^(.*)$"
            },
            "Email": {
              "$id": "#/properties/Email",
              "type": "string",
              "title": "The Email Schema",
              "default": "",
              "examples": [
                ""
              ],
              "minLength": 7,
              "pattern": "^(.*)$",
              "format": "email"
            },
            "Password": {
              "$id": "#/properties/Password",
              "type": "string",
              "title": "The Password Schema",
              "default": "",
              "examples": [
                ""
              ],
              "pattern": "^(.*)$"
            }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
        }
    }
}
```

I'm parsing everything like this:

```
func Validate(data interface{}, r *http.Request) (interface{}, error) {
    // Convert the data struct to a readable JSON bytes
    JSONparams, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Split URL segments so we know what part of the API they are accessing
    modules := strings.Split(r.URL.String(), "/")
    modules = modules[(len(modules) - 1):]

    // Read the schema file
    fileSchema, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("config/schema/schema.json")
    var object interface{}

    // Unmarshal it so we can choose what schema we specifically want
    err = json.Unmarshal(fileSchema, &object)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Choose the preferred schema
    encodedJSON, err := json.Marshal(object.(map[string]interface{})[strings.Join(modules, "") + "s"].(map[string]interface{})[r.Method])
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Load the JSON schema
    schema := gojsonschema.NewStringLoader(string(encodedJSON))

    // Load the JSON params
    document := gojsonschema.NewStringLoader(string(JSONparams))

    // Validate the document
    result, err := gojsonschema.Validate(schema, document)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if !result.Valid() {
        // Map the errors into a new array
        var errors = make(map[string]string)
        for _, err := range result.Errors() {
            errors[err.Field()] = err.Description()
        }

        // Convert the array to an interface that we can convert to JSON
        resultMap := map[string]interface{}{
            "success": false,
            "result": map[string]interface{}{},
            "errors": errors,
        }

        // Convert the interface to a JSON object
        errorObject, err := json.Marshal(resultMap)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        return errorObject, nil
    }

    return nil, nil
}

type CreateParams struct {
    DisplayName     string
    Username        string
    Email           string
    Password        string
}

var (
    response interface{}
    status int = 0
)

func Create(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    status = 0

    // Parse the request so we can access the query parameters
    r.ParseForm()

    // Assign them to the interface variables
    data := &CreateParams{
        DisplayName: r.Form.Get("DisplayName"),
        Username: r.Form.Get("Username"),
        Email: r.Form.Get("Email"),
        Password: r.Form.Get("Password"),
    }

    // Validate the JSON data
    errors, err := schema.Validate(data, r)

    if err != nil {
        responseJSON  := map[string]interface{}{
            "success": false,
            "result": map[string]interface{}{},
        }

        log.Fatal(err.Error())

        response, err = json.Marshal(responseJSON)
        status = http.StatusInternalServerError
    }

    // Catch any errors generated by the validator and assign them to the response interface
    if errors != nil {
        response = errors
        status = http.StatusBadRequest
    }

    // Status has not been set yet, so it's safe to assume that everything went fine
    if status == 0 {
        responseJSON  := map[string]interface{}{
            "success": true,
            "result": map[string]interface{} {
                "DisplayName": data.DisplayName,
                "Username": data.Username,
                "Email": data.Email,
                "Password": nil,
            },
        }

        response, err = json.Marshal(responseJSON)
        status = http.StatusOK
    }

    // We are going to respond with JSON, so set the appropriate header
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    // Write the header and the response
    w.WriteHeader(status)
    w.Write(response.([]byte))
}
```

The reason to why I'm doing it like this is I'm building a REST API and if `api/auth/user` gets a PUT request, I want to be able to specify the data requirements for specifically the "users" parts with the PUT method.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

**EDIT:**
My json data:

```
{
  "DisplayName": "1234",
  "Username": "1234",
  "Email": "test@gmail.com",
  "Password": "123456"
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
This data should fail with the schema.

```
{
  "DisplayName": "1", // min length is 3
  "Username": "", // this field is required but is empty here
  "Email": "testgmail.com", // not following the email format
  "Password": "123456111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" // too long
}
```

Comment: Hi! I'll be able to help best if you provide your full JSON Schema and full JSON instance data you're trying to validate. I'm not familiar with go, but I'll be able to easily tell you if there is a schema issue or not.

Comment: @Relequestual I have updated the post with the full schema and also my JSON data. Thank you.

Comment: I've tested your schema and data using https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net. You can remove `pattern`, `default`, and `examples`, they aren't doing anything here. Also you don't need to specify the `$id` for each field. I'm able to make `required` work as expected. I'm also able to make each field fail validation. I think you may be expecting JSON Schema to do something it is not. Can you provide examples of JSON data you expect to fail validation please?

Comment: @Relequestual Updated. I would also like to point out that required does not seem to override min-length rules for parameters when trying the schema validator you provided.

Comment: I'm not sure how `required` would override `min-length`. Required just means that the object key must be present, and specifies nothing about its value. In terms of your example that should fail: In your schema, "Password" doesn't have a min length set. "Username" and "DisplayName" fail as expected, min length not met. For "format", support for these are optional, and depend on each implementation.

Comment: @Relequestual Indeed. I have printed the JSON schema outputted by my server after all parsing and it is woring fine in the validator. Could schemas be encoding sensitive or some weird crap like that?

Comment: The author of the library you're using is going to take a look. I've discussed this issue with him specifically on our JSON Schema slack. Happy bug hunting! =]

Comment: @Relequestual I appreciate that! Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I manually load the schema and data using `gojsonschema` it works as expected. I suspect that since you're loading the schema in a somewhat complicated fashion the schema you put in ends up being something different than what you'd expect, but since your code samples are all HTTP based I can't really test it out myself.

Comment: I have printed the value of the schema in the end, and used it in the schema validator and in there it works perfectly fine. I'm thinking there must be some other error here that you can't easily spot with the bare eye, like an encoding issue or something?

Comment: I made a quick repo for you, if you'd like to try it out yourself: https://github.com/akkelw/gojsonschema_debug

Comment: The problem is that you get the values from the form, put them in a struct and then convert that struct to JSON. If all values in the form are empty this will still lead to the following JSON: 
`{"DisplayName":"","Username":"","Email":"","Password":""}`
This means that all properties are present, they're just empty, so the required check will pass fine, and the password is actually valid because it passes the regex `^(.*)$`. You should specify `json:omitempty` in the struct fields to remove the empty fields.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this. I was wondering if that actually meant any difference, and that answered my question.